# Use different post per page after first page using Timber?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I have a problem migrating my theme to Timber in regards to how the blog is paginated. On the first page of the blog I want 3 posts, with every page afterwards continuing in groups of 6. (Page 1 as 1,2,3; page 2 as 4,5,6,7,8,9; page 3 as 10,11,12,13,14,15; etc...)

I currently have 11 posts, with '1' being the oldest and '11' being the most recent. The first page is 11, 10, 9, showing it limited to 3. However the next page going back then shows 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, when it should be 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 with another link to go back one more time.

This is what is in my blog.php:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Blog */
global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) {
    $paged = 1;
}

if ($paged == 1) {
    $posts_per_page = 3;
} else {
    $posts_per_page = 6;
}

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged
));
Timber::render('pages/blog.twig',$context);
?>
```

And my twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block main %}
{% for post in posts %}
    <article>
        <a href="{{ post.link }}">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <div class="excerpt">{{ post.content|truncate(40) }}</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
{% endfor %}

<section class="pagination">
    {% if posts.pagination.next %}
        <a href="{{ posts.pagination.next.link }}" class="prev"><span></span>older</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
        <a href="{{ posts.pagination.prev.link }}" class="next">newer<span></span></a>
    {% endif %}
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

#### What version of WordPress, PHP and Timber are you using?

Wordpress 4.9.6
Timber 1.7.1
PHP 7.2.1

#### How did you install Timber?

Upgraded to newest version via plugin updater in WordPress dashboard

#### Update 1

I tried modifying it to use `pre_get_posts`but I'm not sure how it fits together to make the pagination continue another page to show the remaining '2, 1' posts.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Blog */
global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) {
    $paged = 1;
}

if ($paged == 1) {
    $posts_per_page = 3;
} else {
    $posts_per_page = 6;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_query_offset', 1 );
function myprefix_query_offset(&$query) {
    //Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
    if ( ! $query->is_home() ) {
        return;
    }

    //First, define your desired offset...
    if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    if ($paged == 1) {
        $offset = 0;
    } else {
        $offset = 3;
    }

    //Next, determine how many posts per page you want (we'll use WordPress's settings)
    if ($paged == 1) {
        $ppp = 3;
    } else {
        $ppp = 6;
    }

    //Next, detect and handle pagination...
    if ( $query->is_paged ) {
        //Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ($query->query_vars['paged']-1) * $ppp );
        //Apply adjust page offset
        $query->set('offset', $page_offset );
    }
    else {
        //This is the first page. Just use the offset...
        $query->set('offset',$offset);
    }
}

add_filter('found_posts', 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
function myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination($found_posts, $query) {
    //Define our offset again...
    if (!isset($paged) || !$paged) {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    if ($paged == 1) {
        $offset = 0;
    } else {
        $offset = 3;
    }

    //Ensure we're modifying the right query object...
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
        //Reduce WordPress's found_posts count by the offset... 
        return $found_posts - $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged
));
$context['paged'] = $paged;
Timber::render('pages/blog.twig',$context);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to actually to use `offset` parameter but this will break your pagination.

Please refer to this https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination document.

While the approach similar to the one in the docs is preferred you can still work with your example a bit. Something like this may work:

```
if ($paged == 1) {
    $posts_per_page = 3;
    $offset = 0;
} else {
    $posts_per_page = 6;
    $offset = 3 + ($paged-2)*6; 
}

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'offset' => $offset
));
```

Comment: Thanks, trying the offset seemed to work in that the second page now shows '8,7,6,5,4,3' but it stops there without a way to go back one more time to see '2,1'.

Comment: Yes - for that to work you would either need to implement your own pagination or follow the link I have provided in my answer and use `pre_get_posts`